# How to calculate 2x + 4 = 10 using sympy?

Tags: python, sympy

How to calculate `2x + 4 = 10` using Sympy? Is it even possible?
It does not run on Sympy gamma but it runs on *Wolframalpha* and *Cymath*. Is it normal or is there some built-in library that should be used with this type of equation?

Answer (score 2):

To represent it,

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x
>>> from sympy import S, Eq, solve
>>> eq = Eq(2*x + 4, 10)
>>> pprint(eq)
2*x + 4 = 10
```

To solve it:

```
>>> solve(eq)
[3]
```

To interpret input:

```
>>> s = '2*x + 4 = 10'
>>> eq = Eq(*map(S, s.split('=')))
```

Comment: but i am take Equation form user side so how is it possible?

Comment: I updated the answer. If you want less strict input (to recognize `2x` as `2*x` then you should look at `sympy.parsing.parse_expr`.